# Hibernate/JPA : Include field in where clause of update

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

On save(), Hibernate executes SQL like

```
update TABLE_A set COL_A=? , COL_B=? , COL_C=? where COL_PK=?
```

Is there any way to change this to :

```
update TABLE_A set COL_A=? , COL_B=?  where COL_PK=? and COL_C=?
```

The reason for doing this is we have the table partitioned on COL_C and unless we use it in the where clause, it will look through all the partitions.

Comment: Define the partition using hibernate `@DiscriminatorColumn` might be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Find below an snippet which should explain you the principle.

```
int rowsUpdated = entityManager.createQuery("update YourEntity e"
    + " set e.columnA= :columnA"
    + " where e.columnPK = :columnPK"
    + " and e.columnC = :columnC")
    .setParameter("columnA", columnA)
    .setParameter("columnPK", columnPK)
    .setParameter("columnC", columnC)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I know I can write a update query. Because of the way the code is structured, I want it to happen when save() is called on the object.